# willSelectRowAtIndexPath, didSelectRowAtIndexPath are not calling in iphone when using touches began method and performselector

Tags: iphone

I am developing an application, in which one of the screen i am using have tableview, it is tableview controller. i have written custom touchesbegan,touchesmoved,touchesended methods insside a tableview controller class, when ever user presses on any cell touchesbegan method is calling and withing this to detect long tap what i did was

```
[self performSelector:@selector(longTap) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

if user removes his finger before 1sec, in `touchesmoved` and `touchesended` methods i am canceling the `performselector`.

now what happens is when i press & hold for 1min `longTap` method is calling and `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`, `didselectRowAtIndexPath` are not calling. but i need to get the indexpath.row value before performing any action on `longTap` method.
Can any one help me on this issue. please share your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should consider using a gesture recognizer like `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. Fiddling with the touch events yourself is hard and error prone.

It is very easy to break a flow of events that UIKit classes depends upon to function. Gesture recognizers is the public API for hooking into the touch event flow, in simple and advanced easy, without breaking UIKit functionality.

Comment: Thank you for the reply Peylow, definitely i will try this, and i figured out in another way. what i did was in touches began method given a perform-selector after-delay(1.0)sec and called the longTap method after press&hold for 1sec, within the longTap method i have a boolean variable which is set to YES and does nothing in that method, then immediately didselect method of tableiview called in this i checked the bool variable and performed the required action. Previously the blocking element was UIAlertview.